# Como se chama o símbolo "caret" em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução

Existe um nome em Português para o símbolo "caret"?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret

Não é o acento circumflexo, pois têm símbolos diferentes em Unicode.

Comment: Humberto, que símbolo era este, na pergunta? Porque o artigo atual da wikipedia de "[Caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret)" tem o símbolo unicode "U+005E ^ CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT (&Hat;)" que é literalmente o acento circumflexo... e o artigo de "[Caret (proofreading)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_(proofreading))" tem símbolos que não correspondem de maneira nenhuma ao acento circunflexo: "U+2038 ‸ CARET / U+2041 ⁁ CARET INSERTION POINT / U+2380 ⎀ INSERTION SYMBOL".

Answer (score 3):

Esse símbolo chama-se chama-se "**[sinal de] chamada**":

> 8. [Tipografia]  Sinal gráfico com indicação para revisão ou alteração tipográfica.
>
> "chamada", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/chamada [consultado em 30-03-2021].

Isto é exatamente a definição de "caret" dada pelo artigo da Wikipédia "linkado" na pergunta (ênfase minha):

> The caret (/ˈkærɪt/) is a V-shaped grapheme (...) used in proofreading and typography to *indicate that additional material needs to be inserted at this point in the text*.

Este símbolo é aquele "v" que se mete no meio das palavras para indicar uma adição ao texto:
[image: uma imagem a mostrar o símbolo e como é usado]

---

Os espanhóis chamam-lhe [**símbolo de intercalação**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret).

Os brasileiros também parecem chamar-lhe isso, no contexto de programação:

- https://qastack.com.br/superuser/94825/how-to-type-ctrl-
- https://qastack.com.br/ubuntu/211912/whats-the-caret-mean-in-apt-get

Comment: Ótima resposta, ANeves. Uma pergunta: sabes da formalidade desse sinal ou se é arcaico?

Comment: @Schilive Eu usei-o na escola, nos anos 90. Suponho que isso faz dele arcaico?... 

Comment: O WordReference [dá](https://www.wordreference.com/enpt/caret) "*marca de interpolação*".

Comment: NB: Esta resposta está desatualizada (e a pergunta também): o [artigo da Wikipedia sobre o Caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) indica que ele é o acento circunflexo, e [o artigo sobre Caret (proofreading)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_(proofreading)) não tem relação com isto — o símbolo é invertido, em forma de v e não de acento circunflexo.